# M:N table does not update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have m:n relationship between User and Document. I am creating Document object, getting List - setDocumentsForUsers() and then I am persisting that object. Problem is, that document is created in my database, but not M:N relationship. What am I doing wrong? I tried to call flush after persisting, but it did not help at all.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="users_documents",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name="document_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Document> usersDocuments;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Document> sharedDocuments;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(String firstName, String surname, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){this.email = email;}

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public List<Document> getUsersDocuments() {
        return usersDocuments;
    }

    public void setUsersDocuments(List<Document> usersDocuments) {
        this.usersDocuments = usersDocuments;
    }

    public List<Document> getSharedDocuments() {
        return sharedDocuments;
    }

    public void setSharedDocuments(List<Document> sharedDocuments) {
        this.sharedDocuments = sharedDocuments;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return getId() == user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My Document class:

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    @Column(name = "resource_path")
    private String resourcePath;

    @Column(name = "upload_datetime", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date uploadDatetime;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersDocuments")
    private List<User> documentsForUsers;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;


    public Document() {

    }

    public Document(String title, String description){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getResourcePath() {
        return resourcePath;
    }

    public void setResourcePath(String resourcePath) {
        this.resourcePath = resourcePath;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Document{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", resourcePath='" + resourcePath + '\'' +
                ", uploadDatetime=" + uploadDatetime + '\'' +
                ". user=" + user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Document)) return false;
        Document document = (Document) o;
        return getId() == document.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    public Date getUploadDatetime() {
        return uploadDatetime;
    }

    public void setUploadDatetime(Date uploadDatetime) {
   //     Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(uploadDatetime.toString());
        this.uploadDatetime = uploadDatetime;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<User> getDocumentsForUsers() {
        return documentsForUsers;
    }

    public void setDocumentsForUsers(List<User> documentsForUsers) {
        this.documentsForUsers = documentsForUsers;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Perform this:

```
Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByEmail(createdBy);
        Document document = new Document(title, desc);
        document.setUploadDatetime(new Date());
        document.setUser(user.get());

        List<User> users = userService.getUsersByRoles(roles);

        document.setDocumentsForUsers(users);
        saveDocument(document);


@Override
    public void saveDocument(Document document) {
        entityManager.persist(document);
    }
```

Comment: In any relationship there are Owner and Inverse end. Inverse end cares only about itself data, not about relationship, and update only it information without updating a relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add the option to your @ManyToMany annotation: CascadeType.PERSIST.

By default, hibernate doesn't persists your relationship objects.

Try to use:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class **User** is an Owner of relation *@ManyToMany* on

```
List<Document> usersDocuments;
```

as **User** has *@JoinTable*. **Document** class is an *Inverse end*. 
If a Document is persisted then a data will be saved without relations. Because Inverse end cares only about itself but no relations.

By default you can persist a relation only from the owner side.

To be able to **persist a relation from the inverse end** then in your case as I tested:

1. In Document add cascade:

> ```
> @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "usersDocuments")
> private List<User> documentsForUsers;
> ```

and add a new code in your setter:

```
public void setDocumentsForUsers(List<User> documentsForUsers) {
    if (documentsForUsers != null){
        documentsForUsers.forEach(u -> {
            u.getUsersDocuments().add(this); //here you should have not-null list u.getUsersDocuments()
        });
    }
    this.documentsForUsers = documentsForUsers;
}
```

2. In User class add cascade:

> ```
> @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
> ```

and

```
private List<Document> usersDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
```